# jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi fellow stackoverflow:ers,

I'm using the [jQuery Datepicker plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.2/Datepicker), together with [Martin Milesich Timepicker](http://milesich.com/timepicker/) plugin. Everything works great, except for the fact that clicking a date in the datepicker, closes the widget, leaving no time to pick the time.

Question: So I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent the widget from closing when clicking a date, and instead force users to click the "Done" button (that shows up when enabling the "showButtonPanel: true" option), or clicking outside of the widget. I don't want my users having to open the widget twice! See the behavior [online at the timepicker demo](http://milesich.com/tpdemo/)

Any help solving this issue, or even pointers in the right direction, is appreciated!

More info:
I'm using the files supplied from Martins download link: http://milesich.com/tpdemo/timepicker-0.2.0.zip

- jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js
- timepicker.js (latest version 0.2.0)

These are the options I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        duration: '',  
        showTime: true,  
        constrainInput: false,  
        stepMinutes: 5,  
        stepHours: 1, 
        time24h: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        buttonImage: '/static/images/datepicker.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        monthNames: ['Januari','Februari','Mars','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','Augusti','September','Oktober','November','December'],
        showOn: 'both',
        showButtonPanel: true
     });
})
```

Comment: A quick note to say that this issue is no longer a problem in the current version of TimePicker plugin.

Comment: @lucifer: Sorry, no. You are using StackOverflow wrong. If you have a question, write a new one with as much information you can. You will probably get a reply within a couple of hours.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

rather than changing the source it's best to use the existing events

```
onSelect: function() {
    $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;                               
},
onClose: function() {
    $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.

Note: this will remove the "done" button if you have `showButtonPanel: true` enabled. Haven't worked out how to stop this behaviour.

Comment: @PhilMoorhouse A bit late, but maybe still helps someone: in jquery-ui you'll find a `_generateHTML` function which won't add the "done" button if the instance has `inline: true`set. You can search for the only occurence of `ui-datepicker-close` there and get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: @Min Hur: This works little bit good, but if there is a button on the datepicker then it will not remain visible if use this code. Will you please tell the way how to prevent closing the datepicker and prevent buttons on it while selecting dates.

Comment: This solution is not good when you are doing some custom styling with js because it is re-init the datepicker popup. All the changes are gone after $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;

Answer (score 28):

For reference, and since people have asked me this through mail. Here's a code chunk that needs to be added to timepicker.js:

```
/**
 * Don't hide the date picker when clicking a date
 */
$.datepicker._selectDateOverload = $.datepicker._selectDate;
$.datepicker._selectDate = function(id, dateStr) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    inst.inline = true;
    $.datepicker._selectDateOverload(id, dateStr);
    inst.inline = false;
    this._updateDatepicker(inst);
}
```

Good luck in getting it working on your site!

Comment: +1 an old question but still works! thanks for adding this reference.

Comment: @zaf: Thanks for getting back to me, and voting :)

Comment: This works, but scrolls to the top of the screen when the date is selected...at least in Chrome.

Comment: gives me this error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @OmidHezaveh: You probably didn't copy things properly. Note the names _selectDateOverload and _selectDate. They need to be different.

Comment: Thanks @EmilStenström, but I believe in my copy/pasting skills strongly :) I guess the hard part is that I'm injecting script to an already working datepicker. I don't have access to the javascript/html that is already on page! Here's the page that I'm talking about: http://www.etstur.com/Pam-Termal-Hotel/Online-Satis I'd like to change the behaviour of the calendar so that it stills open after picking dates, or at least attach an event to it so that I can do some animation after the date is selected.

Comment: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net refreshes to current month every 2 dates picked. Aug 2016 and it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

You will have to hack the datepicker yourself. This is the code it uses. If it is not inline it will hide when you select a date.

You could pass in your own onSelect method and quickly change the datePicker instance to be inline and then change it back without having to change the datepicker internals but it is a very hacky solution.

```
if (inst.inline)
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
else {
      this._hideDatepicker(null, this._get(inst, 'duration'));
      this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
      if (typeof(inst.input[0]) != 'object')
      inst.input[0].focus(); // restore focus
      this._lastInput = null;
}
```

Comment: Big thanks redsquare, your reply led me in the right direction. It seems onSelect is only triggered when selecting a date, so simply calling show() on the instance on select gives me the behavior I want.
...
onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
    inst.show();
}

Comment: No, my fault. The above throws an error, something that seems to stop the picker from hiding. I still can't get your suggestion to work. If I turn it to "inline", the Done-button disappears, and there's no other way to close the window than to click outside of it. I tried to set a timeout and reset the inline mode to no effect.

Comment: Ok, I found a second way of doing what I want. It's actually possible to override the _selectDate method, where to code you supply above comes from, with a custom method. That method contains exactly the same code as in the original file, but without the "_hideDatepicker" line. Simple, and rather hackish, but it works.

Comment: Glad you sorted it Emil. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution :

```
onSelect: function ( dateText, inst ) {
    ..... // Your code like $(this).val( dateText );`


    //Set inline to true to force "no close"
    inst.inline = true;
},
onClose: function(date,inst){
    //Set inline to false => datapicker is closed
    // onClose is called only if you click outside the datapicker, onSelect will not
    // trig onClose due to inline = true
   inst.inline = false;
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Why all comments provide workaround? it is straigtfarword:

Use inline calendar with altField :)

```
    <input type="text" id="alternate" size="30" />
    <div id="datepicker"></div>

    <script>
       $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          altField: "#alternate"
       });
    </script>
```

check this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/menocomp/y2s662b0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Following with what Emil suggested, I found a nicer and easier way to modify the widget to support a not closing widget on select event.

First, I added another property to the defaults dict on the widget:

```
closeOnSelect:true //True to close the widget when you select a date
```

Second, find this statement in the _selectDate method:

```
if (inst.inline)
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
else {
        ...
    }
```

And change the condition to be like this:

```
var closeOnSelect = this._get(inst, "closeOnSelect");        
if (inst.inline || !closeOnSelect)
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
else {
        ...
    }
```

Give it a try, it is working for me. I did it over the JQuery UI 1.8.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, if you are using jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js and jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js, you could modify the jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js:
from:

```
if(a.inline)this._updateDatepicker(a);
```

into:

```
if(a.inline || !this._get(a, 'closeOnSelect'))this._updateDatepicker(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

well this a dirty workaround...but it works for me...even with *showButtonPanel: true*

```
  $(function() {
    var dp_c = null, dp_once = false;
    $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onSelect: function() {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;  
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').find('.ui-datepicker-buttonpane').append(dp_c);
        }, 1);

      },
      onClose: function() {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
      }
    }).click(function () {
      if(!dp_once) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          dp_c = $('#ui-datepicker-div').find('.ui-datepicker-close').clone();
        }, 500);
        dp_once = !!1;
      }
    });

    $('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker( "hide" );
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override native js function:

```
 /* Update the input field with the selected date. */
        _selectDate: function(id, dateStr) {
            var target = $(id);
            var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
            dateStr = (dateStr != null ? dateStr : this._formatDate(inst));
            if (inst.input)
                inst.input.val(dateStr);
            this._updateAlternate(inst);
            var onSelect = this._get(inst, 'onSelect');
            if (onSelect)
                onSelect.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [dateStr, inst]);  // trigger custom callback
            else if (inst.input)
                inst.input.trigger('change'); // fire the change event
            if (inst.inline)
                this._updateDatepicker(inst);
            else {
                if(inst.settings.hideOnSelect != false){
                    this._hideDatepicker();
                }
                this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
                if (typeof(inst.input[0]) != 'object')
                    inst.input.focus(); // restore focus
                this._lastInput = null;
            }
        },
```

And add appropriate option to datepicker configuration, as example:

```
var defaultDatePickerOptions = {
        hideOnSelect: false,
        ...
    }; 
 var birthDate = jQuery.extend({}, defaultDatePickerOptions);
 $('#birthdate').datepicker(birthDate);
```