# Prevent jQuery Datepicker from closing by clicking anywhere

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to limit the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to be closed only by clicking on the input field ?

Comment: There are ten million jQuery date pickers on the Internet. Even though probably only one is called "jQuery datepicker", please always provide a link to the specific one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

assuming its the UI datepicker plugin

see here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-plugin-how-to-prevent-the-datepicker-calendar-popup-from-closing

and here: [jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date)

Comment: Thanks. But those scripts are just for preventing datepicker from closing by clicking on a date. And the scripts are not understandable to be customized :(.

Answer (score 1):

Just override _checkExternalClick function like this:

```
jQuery.datepicker._checkExternalClick = function() {};
```