# jQuery UI datepicker (with time addon) issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to implement the jQuery UI Date Picker with the Time Picker addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

For some reason, I'm getting NaN instead of numbers and the little slider isn't showing up. I downloaded Redmound theme from the UI, so that might have something to do with it? But I've also copied the code from the demo website.

Any ideas?

Here's the site I'm trying to get it working on:

http://citysouthphysio.website.2010.360southclients.com/book-appointment.html

The code is:

```
jQuery('#date').datetimepicker({
    duration: '',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    ampm: true,
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 16
});
```

And the jquery timepicker js is:

```
/*
* jQuery timepicker addon
* By: Trent Richardson [http://trentrichardson.com]
* Version 0.6.2
* Last Modified: 9/26/2010
* 
* Copyright 2010 Trent Richardson
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
* http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/GPL-LICENSE.txt
* http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/MIT-LICENSE.txt
* 
* HERES THE CSS:
* .ui-timepicker-div dl{ text-align: left; }
* .ui-timepicker-div dl dt{ height: 25px; }
* .ui-timepicker-div dl dd{ margin: -25px 0 10px 65px; }
*/

(function($) {
    function Timepicker(singleton) {
        if(typeof(singleton) === 'boolean' && singleton == true) {
            this.regional = []; // Available regional settings, indexed by language code
            this.regional[''] = { // Default regional settings
                currentText: 'Now',
                ampm: false,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
                timeOnlyTitle: 'Choose Time',
                timeText: 'Time',
                hourText: 'Hour',
                minuteText: 'Minute',
                secondText: 'Second'
            };
            this.defaults = { // Global defaults for all the datetime picker instances
                showButtonPanel: true,
                timeOnly: false,
                showHour: true,
                showMinute: true,
                showSecond: false,
                showTime: true,
                stepHour: 0.05,
                stepMinute: 0.05,
                stepSecond: 0.05,
                hour: 0,
                minute: 0,
                second: 0,
                hourMin: 0,
                minuteMin: 0,
                secondMin: 0,
                hourMax: 23,
                minuteMax: 59,
                secondMax: 59,
                alwaysSetTime: true
            };
            $.extend(this.defaults, this.regional['']);
        } else {
            this.defaults = $.extend({}, $.timepicker.defaults);
        }

    }

    Timepicker.prototype = {
        $input: null,
        $timeObj: null,
        inst: null,
        hour_slider: null,
        minute_slider: null,
        second_slider: null,
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        ampm: '',
        formattedDate: '',
        formattedTime: '',
        formattedDateTime: '',

        //########################################################################
        // add our sliders to the calendar
        //########################################################################
        addTimePicker: function(dp_inst) {
            var tp_inst = this;
            var currDT = this.$input.val();
            var regstr = this.defaults.timeFormat.toString()
                .replace(/h{1,2}/ig, '(\\d?\\d)')
                .replace(/m{1,2}/ig, '(\\d?\\d)')
                .replace(/s{1,2}/ig, '(\\d?\\d)')
                .replace(/t{1,2}/ig, '(am|pm|a|p)?')
                .replace(/\s/g, '\\s?') + '$';

            if (!this.defaults.timeOnly) {
                //the time should come after x number of characters and a space.  x = at least the length of text specified by the date format
                var dp_dateFormat = $.datepicker._get(dp_inst, 'dateFormat');
                regstr = '.{' + dp_dateFormat.length + ',}\\s+' + regstr;
            }

            var order = this.getFormatPositions();
            var treg = currDT.match(new RegExp(regstr, 'i'));

            if (treg) {
                if (order.t !== -1) {
                    this.ampm = ((treg[order.t] === undefined || treg[order.t].length === 0) ? '' : (treg[order.t].charAt(0).toUpperCase() == 'A') ? 'AM' : 'PM').toUpperCase();
                }

                if (order.h !== -1) {
                    if (this.ampm == 'AM' && treg[order.h] == '12') {
                        // 12am = 0 hour
                        this.hour = 0;
                    } else if (this.ampm == 'PM' && treg[order.h] != '12') {
                        // 12pm = 12 hour, any other pm = hour + 12
                        this.hour = (parseFloat(treg[order.h]) + 12).toFixed(0);
                    } else {
                        this.hour = treg[order.h];
                    }
                }

                if (order.m !== -1) {
                    this.minute = treg[order.m];
                }

                if (order.s !== -1) {
                    this.second = treg[order.s];
                }
            }

            tp_inst.timeDefined = (treg) ? true : false;

            if (typeof(dp_inst.stay_open) !== 'boolean' || dp_inst.stay_open === false) {
            // wait for datepicker to create itself.. 60% of the time it works every time..
                setTimeout(function() {
                    tp_inst.injectTimePicker(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                }, 10);
            } else {
                tp_inst.injectTimePicker(dp_inst, tp_inst);
            }

        },

        //########################################################################
        // figure out position of time elements.. cause js cant do named captures
        //########################################################################
        getFormatPositions: function() {
            var finds = this.defaults.timeFormat.toLowerCase().match(/(h{1,2}|m{1,2}|s{1,2}|t{1,2})/g);
            var orders = { h: -1, m: -1, s: -1, t: -1 };

            if (finds) {
                for (var i = 0; i < finds.length; i++) {
                    if (orders[finds[i].toString().charAt(0)] == -1) {
                        orders[finds[i].toString().charAt(0)] = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return orders;
        },

        //########################################################################
        // generate and inject html for timepicker into ui datepicker
        //########################################################################
        injectTimePicker: function(dp_inst, tp_inst) {
            var $dp = dp_inst.dpDiv;
            var opts = tp_inst.defaults;

            // Added by Peter Medeiros:
            // - Figure out what the hour/minute/second max should be based on the step values.
            // - Example: if stepMinute is 15, then minMax is 45.
            var hourMax = opts.hourMax - (opts.hourMax % opts.stepHour);
            var minMax  = opts.minuteMax - (opts.minuteMax % opts.stepMinute);
            var secMax  = opts.secondMax - (opts.secondMax % opts.stepSecond);

            // Prevent displaying twice
            if ($dp.find("div#ui-timepicker-div-"+ dp_inst.id).length === 0) {
                var noDisplay = ' style="display:none;"';
                var html =
                    '<div class="ui-timepicker-div" id="ui-timepicker-div-'+ dp_inst.id +'"><dl>' +
                        '<dt class="ui_tpicker_time_label" id="ui_tpicker_time_label_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showTime)   ? '' : noDisplay) + '>'+ opts.timeText +'</dt>' +
                        '<dd class="ui_tpicker_time" id="ui_tpicker_time_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showTime)   ? '' : noDisplay) + '></dd>' +
                        '<dt class="ui_tpicker_hour_label" id="ui_tpicker_hour_label_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'   + ((opts.showHour)   ? '' : noDisplay) + '>'+ opts.hourText +'</dt>' +
                        '<dd class="ui_tpicker_hour" id="ui_tpicker_hour_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showHour)   ? '' : noDisplay) + '></dd>' +
                        '<dt class="ui_tpicker_minute_label" id="ui_tpicker_minute_label_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showMinute) ? '' : noDisplay) + '>'+ opts.minuteText +'</dt>' +
                        '<dd class="ui_tpicker_minute" id="ui_tpicker_minute_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showMinute) ? '' : noDisplay) + '></dd>' +
                        '<dt class="ui_tpicker_second_label" id="ui_tpicker_second_label_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showSecond) ? '' : noDisplay) + '>'+ opts.secondText +'</dt>' +
                        '<dd class="ui_tpicker_second" id="ui_tpicker_second_'+ dp_inst.id +'"'    + ((opts.showSecond) ? '' : noDisplay) + '></dd>' +
                    '</dl></div>';
                $tp = $(html);

                // if we only want time picker...
                if (opts.timeOnly === true) {
                    $tp.prepend(
                        '<div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">' +
                            '<div class="ui-datepicker-title">'+ opts.timeOnlyTitle +'</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                    $dp.find('.ui-datepicker-header, .ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
                }

                tp_inst.hour_slider = $tp.find('#ui_tpicker_hour_'+ dp_inst.id).slider({
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    value: tp_inst.hour,
                    min: opts.hourMin,
                    max: hourMax,
                    step: opts.stepHour,
                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                        tp_inst.hour_slider.slider( "option", "value", ui.value );
                        tp_inst.onTimeChange(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                    }
                });

                // Updated by Peter Medeiros:
                // - Pass in Event and UI instance into slide function
                tp_inst.minute_slider = $tp.find('#ui_tpicker_minute_'+ dp_inst.id).slider({
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    value: tp_inst.minute,
                    min: opts.minuteMin,
                    max: minMax,
                    step: opts.stepMinute,
                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                        // update the global minute slider instance value with the current slider value
                        tp_inst.minute_slider.slider( "option", "value", ui.value );
                        tp_inst.onTimeChange(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                    }
                });

                tp_inst.second_slider = $tp.find('#ui_tpicker_second_'+ dp_inst.id).slider({
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    value: tp_inst.second,
                    min: opts.secondMin,
                    max: secMax,
                    step: opts.stepSecond,
                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                        tp_inst.second_slider.slider( "option", "value", ui.value );
                        tp_inst.onTimeChange(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                    }
                });

                $dp.find('.ui-datepicker-calendar').after($tp);

                tp_inst.$timeObj = $('#ui_tpicker_time_'+ dp_inst.id);

                if (dp_inst !== null) {
                    var timeDefined = tp_inst.timeDefined;
                    tp_inst.onTimeChange(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                    tp_inst.timeDefined = timeDefined;
                }
            }
        },

        //########################################################################
        // when a slider moves..
        // on time change is also called when the time is updated in the text field
        //########################################################################
        onTimeChange: function(dp_inst, tp_inst) {
            var hour   = tp_inst.hour_slider.slider('value');
            var minute = tp_inst.minute_slider.slider('value');
            var second = tp_inst.second_slider.slider('value');
            var ampm = (hour < 12) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
            var hasChanged = false;

            // If the update was done in the input field, this field should not be updated.
            // If the update was done using the sliders, update the input field.
            if (tp_inst.hour != hour || tp_inst.minute != minute || tp_inst.second != second || (tp_inst.ampm.length > 0 && tp_inst.ampm != ampm)) {
                hasChanged = true;
            }

            tp_inst.hour = parseFloat(hour).toFixed(0);
            tp_inst.minute = parseFloat(minute).toFixed(0);
            tp_inst.second = parseFloat(second).toFixed(0);
            tp_inst.ampm = ampm;

            tp_inst.formatTime(tp_inst);
            tp_inst.$timeObj.text(tp_inst.formattedTime);

            if (hasChanged) {
                tp_inst.updateDateTime(dp_inst, tp_inst);
                tp_inst.timeDefined = true;
            }
        },

        //########################################################################
        // format the time all pretty...
        //########################################################################
        formatTime: function(tp_inst) {
            var tmptime = tp_inst.defaults.timeFormat.toString();
            var hour12 = ((tp_inst.ampm == 'AM') ? (tp_inst.hour) : (tp_inst.hour % 12));
            hour12 = (hour12 === 0) ? 12 : hour12;

            if (tp_inst.defaults.ampm === true) {
                tmptime = tmptime.toString()
                    .replace(/hh/g, ((hour12 < 10) ? '0' : '') + hour12)
                    .replace(/h/g, hour12)
                    .replace(/mm/g, ((tp_inst.minute < 10) ? '0' : '') + tp_inst.minute)
                    .replace(/m/g, tp_inst.minute)
                    .replace(/ss/g, ((tp_inst.second < 10) ? '0' : '') + tp_inst.second)
                    .replace(/s/g, tp_inst.second)
                    .replace(/TT/g, tp_inst.ampm.toUpperCase())
                    .replace(/tt/g, tp_inst.ampm.toLowerCase())
                    .replace(/T/g, tp_inst.ampm.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
                    .replace(/t/g, tp_inst.ampm.charAt(0).toLowerCase());

            } else {
                tmptime = tmptime.toString()
                    .replace(/hh/g, ((tp_inst.hour < 10) ? '0' : '') + tp_inst.hour)
                    .replace(/h/g, tp_inst.hour)
                    .replace(/mm/g, ((tp_inst.minute < 10) ? '0' : '') + tp_inst.minute)
                    .replace(/m/g, tp_inst.minute)
                    .replace(/ss/g, ((tp_inst.second < 10) ? '0' : '') + tp_inst.second)
                    .replace(/s/g, tp_inst.second);
                tmptime = $.trim(tmptime.replace(/t/gi, ''));
            }

            tp_inst.formattedTime = tmptime;
            return tp_inst.formattedTime;
        },

        //########################################################################
        // update our input with the new date time..
        //########################################################################
        updateDateTime: function(dp_inst, tp_inst) {
            //var dt = this.$input.datepicker('getDate');
            var dt = new Date(dp_inst.selectedYear, dp_inst.selectedMonth, dp_inst.selectedDay);
            var dateFmt = $.datepicker._get(dp_inst, 'dateFormat');
            var formatCfg = $.datepicker._getFormatConfig(dp_inst);
            this.formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFmt, (dt === null ? new Date() : dt), formatCfg);
            var formattedDateTime = this.formattedDate;
            var timeAvailable = dt !== null && tp_inst.timeDefined;

            if(this.defaults.timeOnly === true){
                formattedDateTime = this.formattedTime;
            }
            else if (this.defaults.timeOnly !== true && (this.defaults.alwaysSetTime || timeAvailable)) {
                formattedDateTime += ' ' + this.formattedTime;
            }

            this.formattedDateTime = formattedDateTime;
            this.$input.val(formattedDateTime);
            this.$input.trigger("change");
        },

        setDefaults: function(settings) {
            extendRemove(this.defaults, settings || {});
            return this;
        }
    };

    //########################################################################
    // extend timepicker to datepicker
    //########################################################################        
    jQuery.fn.datetimepicker = function(o) {
        var opts = (o === undefined ? {} : o);
        var input = $(this);
        var tp = new Timepicker();
        var inlineSettings = {};

        for (var attrName in tp.defaults) {
            var attrValue = input.attr('time:' + attrName);
            if (attrValue) {
                try {
                    inlineSettings[attrName] = eval(attrValue);
                } catch (err) {
                    inlineSettings[attrName] = attrValue;
                }
            }
        }
        tp.defaults = $.extend(tp.defaults, inlineSettings);

        var beforeShowFunc = function(input, inst) {
            tp.hour = tp.defaults.hour;
            tp.minute = tp.defaults.minute;
            tp.second = tp.defaults.second;
            tp.ampm = '';
            tp.$input = $(input);
            tp.inst = inst;
            tp.addTimePicker(inst);
            if ($.isFunction(opts.beforeShow)) {
                opts.beforeShow(input, inst);
            }
        };

        var onChangeMonthYearFunc = function(year, month, inst) {
            // Update the time as well : this prevents the time from disappearing from the input field.
            tp.updateDateTime(inst, tp);
            if ($.isFunction(opts.onChangeMonthYear)) {
                opts.onChangeMonthYear(year, month, inst);
            }
        };

        var onCloseFunc = function(dateText, inst) {
            if(tp.timeDefined === true && input.val() != '') {
                tp.updateDateTime(inst, tp);
            }
            if ($.isFunction(opts.onClose)) {
                opts.onClose(dateText, inst);
            }
        };

        tp.defaults = $.extend({}, tp.defaults, opts, {
            beforeShow: beforeShowFunc,
            onChangeMonthYear: onChangeMonthYearFunc,
            onClose: onCloseFunc,
            timepicker: tp // add timepicker as a property of datepicker: $.datepicker._get(dp_inst, 'timepicker');
        });

        $(this).datepicker(tp.defaults);

    };

    //########################################################################
    // shorthand just to use timepicker..
    //########################################################################
    jQuery.fn.timepicker = function(opts) {
        opts = $.extend(opts, { timeOnly: true });
        $(this).datetimepicker(opts);
    };

    //########################################################################
    // the bad hack :/ override datepicker so it doesnt close on select
    // inspired: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date/1762378#1762378
    //########################################################################
    $.datepicker._base_selectDate = $.datepicker._selectDate;
    $.datepicker._selectDate = function (id, dateStr) {
        var target = $(id);
        var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
        var tp_inst = $.datepicker._get(inst, 'timepicker');

        if(tp_inst){
            inst.inline = true;
            inst.stay_open = true;
            $.datepicker._base_selectDate(id, dateStr);
            inst.stay_open = false;
            inst.inline = false;
            this._notifyChange(inst);
            this._updateDatepicker(inst);
        }
        else{
            $.datepicker._base_selectDate(id, dateStr);
        }
    };

    //#############################################################################################
    // second bad hack :/ override datepicker so it triggers an event when changing the input field
    // and does not redraw the datepicker on every selectDate event
    //#############################################################################################
    $.datepicker._base_updateDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        if (typeof(inst.stay_open) !== 'boolean' || inst.stay_open === false) {
            this._base_updateDatepicker(inst);
            // Reload the time control when changing something in the input text field.
            this._beforeShow(inst.input, inst);
        }
    };

    $.datepicker._beforeShow = function(input, inst) {
        var beforeShow = this._get(inst, 'beforeShow');
        if (beforeShow) {
            inst.stay_open = true;
            beforeShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst.input, inst]);
            inst.stay_open = false;
        }
    };

    //#######################################################################################
    // third bad hack :/ override datepicker so it allows spaces and colan in the input field
    //#######################################################################################
    $.datepicker._base_doKeyPress = $.datepicker._doKeyPress;
    $.datepicker._doKeyPress = function(event) {
        var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
        var tp_inst = $.datepicker._get(inst, 'timepicker');

        if(tp_inst){
            if ($.datepicker._get(inst, 'constrainInput')) {
                var dateChars = $.datepicker._possibleChars($.datepicker._get(inst, 'dateFormat'));
                var chr = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode === undefined ? event.keyCode : event.charCode);
                var chrl = chr.toLowerCase();
                // keyCode == 58 => ":"
                // keyCode == 32 => " "
                return event.ctrlKey || (chr < ' ' || !dateChars || dateChars.indexOf(chr) > -1 || event.keyCode == 58 || event.keyCode == 32 || chr == ':' || chr == ' ' || chrl == 'a' || chrl == 'p' || charl == 'm');
            }
        }
        else{
            return $.datepicker._base_doKeyPress(event);
        }

    };

    //#######################################################################################
    // override "Today" button to also grab the time.
    //#######################################################################################
    $.datepicker._base_gotoToday = $.datepicker._gotoToday;
    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
        $.datepicker._base_gotoToday(id);

        var target = $(id);
        var dp_inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
        var tp_inst = $.datepicker._get(dp_inst, 'timepicker');

        if(tp_inst){
            var date = new Date();
            var hour = date.getHours();
            var minute = date.getMinutes();
            var second = date.getSeconds();

            //check if within min/max times..
            if( (hour < tp_inst.defaults.hourMin || hour > tp_inst.defaults.hourMax) || (minute < tp_inst.defaults.minuteMin || minute > tp_inst.defaults.minuteMax) || (second < tp_inst.defaults.secondMin || second > tp_inst.defaults.secondMax) ){                    
                hour = tp_inst.defaults.hourMin;
                minute = tp_inst.defaults.minuteMin;
                second = tp_inst.defaults.secondMin;                
            }

            tp_inst.hour_slider.slider('value', hour );
            tp_inst.minute_slider.slider('value', minute );
            tp_inst.second_slider.slider('value', second );

            tp_inst.onTimeChange(dp_inst, tp_inst);
        }
    };

    //#######################################################################################
    // jQuery extend now ignores nulls!
    //#######################################################################################
    function extendRemove(target, props) {
        $.extend(target, props);
        for (var name in props)
            if (props[name] == null || props[name] == undefined)
                target[name] = props[name];
        return target;
    };

    $.timepicker = new Timepicker(true); // singleton instance
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put the script inside Joomla, it was conflicting with MooTools. I removed MooTools and it works now.

If anyone else is using this inside joomla, here's how to remove mootools from your template.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {
    $headerstuff = $this->getHeadData();
    $headerstuff['scripts'] = array();
    $this->setHeadData($headerstuff); 
};
```