# prevent datepicker close when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery datepicker .I want to prevent close functionality when clicking outside of calendar dialog box.

url:-http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

In `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` this is the code for hiding calendar when clicking outside:

```
...
if (!$.datepicker.initialized) {
    $(document).mousedown($.datepicker._checkExternalClick);
    $.datepicker.initialized = true;
}
...
```

So you can remove this event handler by using:

```
$(document).unbind('mousedown', $.datepicker._checkExternalClick);
```

Comment: +1 to support your answer, here is the a fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/m98FG/

Comment: It works Good ..

Answer (score 1):

If you create the datapicker on a div rather then an input box it will stay open all the time.
Is this what you want or should it be clicked upon to open and then stay open forever?

Comment: it should be a comment not an answer!!

Comment: create the datepicker on a div sounds like a solution to me ..

Answer (score 0):

assuming its the UI datepicker plugin

see here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-plugin-how-to-prevent-the-datepicker-calendar-popup-from-closing

and here: [jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date)

Comment: your solution is not valid for this problem.