# month picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello am not able to display a month picker placed inside a table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>  
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>
        window.onload = function () {
  PreLoadSection();
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="variables" name="variables" style="width:100%; overflow:auto; overflow: scroll;">          
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

above is my htm code and below my .js file

```
function PreLoadSection()
{
 LoadSectionStratified();
}
function LoadSectionStratified() {
   $('#variables').append($('<table id="variables_table">'));
  $('#variables').append($('<tr>'));
  $('#variables').append('<th style="border: 10px">month picker</th>');
      $('#variables').append($('</tr>'));

   $('#variables').append($('<tr>'));
   AddDate_MonthYear_StratifiedSection();
 $('#variables').append($('</tr>'));
     $('#variables').append($('</table>'));
 $('#variables').trigger('create');
}

function AddDate_MonthYear_StratifiedSection() {
 table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="name1" id="id1" value="" class="date-picker"></td>';
 $('#variables').append(table_html);
}
```

above code is how am implemeting it but it doesnt work. am using firefox version 24.
on window load i call the preload function that calls the LoadSectionStratified function

Comment: Show a *complete* example, including the included libraries and definitions of variables (`control_id` etc). Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: datepicker is not a jQuery function, it's included in jQueryUI. Did you remember to load jQueryUI after jQuery? You may also want to append jQuery UI as a tag to your question after javascript and jquery.

Comment: @Juhana -i have tried to edit the code hope it will make sence to you because its a very large program and most of the code are referencing other things making it a long chain to get everything

Comment: @ Eirinn-i have included jQueryUI after jQuery as shown in the edited code above

Comment: It looks to me that you're trying to initialize the datepicker before the input element exists. At what point do you call `LoadSectionStratified()`?

Comment: @Juhana -i have edited the code to provide the info u are asking.on window laod event i call the PreLoadSection function(this happens on the .html) which inturns calls the LoadSectionStratified function. hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be because it's a newly appended DOM element, rewrite your `$('.date-picker')` as:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.date-picker', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
       //Options
    });
});
```

Which will listen to the entire document for any `$('.date-picker')` which currently exists. I've added a demo with your Code for example:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dHYfv/5/

As [Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana) mentions, it'll be cleaner to initialise it upon appending it to the DOM, Adjust:

```
var opts = {
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       showButtonPanel: true,
       dateFormat: 'MM yy',
           onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
              var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
              var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
              $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
           }
       };

function AddDate_MonthYear_StratifiedSection() {
    var table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;">'+ 
                     '<input name="name1" id="id1" '+ 
                            'value="" class="date-picker" />'+
                     '</td>';

    $('#variables').append(table_html)
                   .find('.date-picker')
                   .datepicker( opts );
}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dHYfv/6/

Comment: this approach is giving me some light.now why is it that when i click on the month date control for the 1st time it doesn't do anything but only until i click outside the control then back before it works?

Comment: I've changed my answer, change `click` to `focus`, that's because it's initialised the `datepicker` after you've already completed the select event, focus would allow it to initialise before the click is complete.

Comment: It would be cleaner to initialize the datepicker only once, when the input field is created.

Comment: @JoseLuke ??? JoseLuke - I've just seen you've made another question and you've never accepted/marked any of your previous questions, please don't abuse SO like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399314/document-onclick-function-not-working-properly I've also corrected the `click` function, because it was the wrong one to use.

Comment: @MackieeE- i cant ignore anything from you guys because without you my career is doomed! so if it was an offense to post that question am very sorry...i didn't know it was abuse of SO. i was just about to accept your answer when u posted this. hope you are still willing to help me because your approach is what i have implemented and i wanted the same approach for time control(both 12hr and 24hr). hope my apology is accepted

Comment: @JoseLuke No worries Jose, I just saw the other question and it seemed you had just jumped away from this one, I'm sorry too! Thank you for coming back =)

Comment: @MackieeE- one last question please...why is it that when i click on today in the month picker it selects current month and year and collapses the month picker window without waiting for me to click done. this has the side effect of not allowing the uset to click on the same month picker control again unless they select others controls before coming back to it?

Comment: with this one wen i click on a specific date the done disappears and it doesn't re appear

Comment: It's meant to close upon clicking, other people have tried what you are asking, but they've had to alter the jQuery source code or whatnot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39347/discussion-between-joseluke-and-mackieee)