# $(document).on('click','',function(){}) not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

hae, am working with `$(document).on('click','',function(){});` but its not working as i want
below is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.date-picker', function () {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>



table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="' + control_id + '" id="' + control_id + '" value="' + row_val + '" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "calbox", "useClearButton": true}\' ></td>';
  $('#variables').append(table_html);
```

The above code creates a month year picker.  It works fine.
But when I click for the 1st time, the month picker control does nothing. When I clicked outside it and click on it again, it worked.
Any idea  or suggestions on how the click event will be detected on 1st time click will be highly appreciated

Comment: Why do you create the date pickers when you click on the document? Why not just `$('.date-picker').datepicker({...})`?

Comment: it is because when the first click handppens the widget is not initialized

Comment: It is because only while clicking, date picker is initialized. So it is working in the second click

Comment: whether the elements are created dynamically

Comment: You're using jQuery datepicker.  but why do you have `type="date"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try [show()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.date-picker', function () {
        var datepicker = $(this).data('uidatepicker');
        if(datepicker) return;
        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        }).datepicker('show');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QRVSw/)

Comment: thanks for the answers guys...i got solution from MackieeE. i had ask the same question twice without my knowledge. i was mayb because of pressure from my work.