# Newly added buttons are not showing up in Datepicker while clicking on Prev and Next buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have include jquery UI date picker in my UI. I have removed Today and close buttons from show panel as below.

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
  display:none;
} 
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-close {
  display:none;
}
```

And after that i have added 3 new buttons in the show panel. While clicking on the textbox i am able to see all three buttons. But while clicking on prev and next months buttons i couldn't see any buttons. Show panel is empty.

Why this is happening like that?

My jQuery code is below to add new buttons.

```
$(dateFrom).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    maxDate: '+30Y',
    yearRange: '1999:c',
    beforeShow: function (input) {
        setTimeout(function () {

            var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            var btn1Day = $('<button class="ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">1 Day</button>');
            var btn2Day = $('<button class="ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">2 Days</button>');
            var btn7Day = $('<button class="ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">7 Days</button>');

            btn1Day.bind("click", function () {
                buttonPane.hide();
                var date2 = $(input).datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                $(dateTo).datepicker('setDate', date2);
                $(dateTo).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
                $(input).datepicker('hide');
            });

            btn2Day.bind("click", function () {
                var date2 = $(input).datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 2);
                $(dateTo).datepicker('setDate', date2);
                $(dateTo).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
                $(input).datepicker('hide');
            });

            btn7Day.bind("click", function () {
                var date2 = $(input).datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);
                $(dateTo).datepicker('setDate', date2);
                $(dateTo).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
                $(input).datepicker('hide');
            });


            btn1Day.appendTo(buttonPane);
            btn2Day.appendTo(buttonPane);
            btn7Day.appendTo(buttonPane);

        }, 1);

    },
    onClose: function (input) {
        if ($(dateFrom).val() != "mm/dd/yyyy") {
            $(dateTo).datepicker("option", "minDate", $(dateFrom).val());
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (date, input) {
        $(dateFrom).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
        $(input).datepicker('show');
        $(date).removeClass('ui-datepicker-calendar ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: How/where have you added them.  Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker re-draws itself on each navigation of month/year so you have to add your manual buttons each time.  I have amended the code to implement this with the `onChangeMonthYear` and `beforeShow`

Also I have split out the listener to work for all `buttons` with a class `my-button` and then use a `data` attribute to get the number of days it needs to add.

Here is the modified code which does roughly what I think you wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dateFrom = '#datepickerfrom';
    dateTo = '#datepickerto';
    $(dateTo).datepicker();

    //datepicker override to prevent closing on date-selection
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1762378/1672632
    $.datepicker._selectDateOverload = $.datepicker._selectDate;
    $.datepicker._selectDate = function (id, dateStr) {
        var target = $(id);
        var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
        inst.inline = true;
        $.datepicker._selectDateOverload(id, dateStr);
        inst.inline = false;
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
    }

    // Delegated click listener
    $(document).on("click", '.my-button', function () {
        var input = $(this).parents('.ui-datepicker').get(0);
        var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
        buttonPane.hide();
        var date2 = $(dateFrom).datepicker('getDate');
        var myDays = $(this).data('days');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + myDays);
        $(dateTo).datepicker('setDate', date2);
        $(dateTo).removeClass('blur').addClass('focus');
        $(input).datepicker('hide');
    });

    function addButtons(input) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            var btn1Day = $('<button data-days="1" class="my-button ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">1 Day</button>');
            var btn2Day = $('<button data-days="2" class="my-button ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">2 Days</button>');
            var btn7Day = $('<button data-days="7" class="my-button ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">7 Days</button>');
            btn1Day.appendTo(buttonPane);
            btn2Day.appendTo(buttonPane);
            btn7Day.appendTo(buttonPane);
        }, 1);

    }

    $(dateFrom).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        yearRange: '1999:c',
        beforeShow: function (input) {
            addButtons(input);
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, input) {
            addButtons(input);
        },
        onClose: function (date, input) {
            if ($(dateFrom).val() != "mm/dd/yyyy") {
                $(dateTo).datepicker("option", "minDate", $(dateFrom).val());
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (date, input) {
            // Got to call addButtons again on selection of a date.
            addButtons(input);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/5m4tP/1/

Comment: I am getting one more issue on button panel. If i am entering date manually in the textbox, button panel is getting disappeared from DatePicker. Any help on this.