# jQuery Datepicker - keep open after selecting a date and close with the button "Done"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I honestly hope you can help me with that as I have spent quite some time searching on the net for appropriate solutions and could not find any.

The issue I am having is that I have a jQuery datepicker which I would like to keep open after selecting a date and then close it when clicking the button "Done" underneath it. The closest thing I found is coming from a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date) from 2012, but unfortunately it hides the buttons coming from the `showButtonPanel: true` option.

So this is a snapshot of my latest "try" which again it doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function(){
      $(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

The calendar gets triggered from:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" path="startDate" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

FYI - Im using jQuery 1.7.2.min.js (unfortunately I cannot update for safety and security reasons), jQuery-ui 1.10.3 and of course, Bootstrap (version 3.0.3 although I am not sure if this will help).
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uc7dwoa/

This is doing the trick in the onSelect:

```
if (inst.inline)
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
else {
      this._hideDatepicker(null, this._get(inst, 'duration'));
      this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
      if (typeof(inst.input[0]) != 'object')
      inst.input[0].focus(); // restore focus
      this._lastInput = null;
}
```

Here the reference of the answer with the used code:
[jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, @ggzone. I have now implemented it, but there is a new issue. Once I click on a day, it doesn't close the calendar, and it keeps the buttons, but it takes me to the top of the page. I notice the URL adds a hash-tag at the end (ex: before clicking date - www.example.com/test; after clicking a day - www.example.com/test#). So it is still not fully working solution. Also, I saw in your fiddle that you are using jquery 1.9.1, and as I have mentioned in my original post, I have to make it work with 1.7.2

Comment: Your answer resolves in an error, `this._get is not a function`.