# How to make jQuery datepicker not to hide even after the date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I don't want to close the calendar control even after the date is selected from the datepicker. Right now it is hiding after the date is selected.
My requirement is user can select date first then can change month and year. But once user selects date the datepicker is hiding. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

**Note:** I don't want to use div tag, instead I want to use input type and need to show date picker on focus and should stay till the focus it taken by other element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't want to use it on div tag instead I want this on input type and to be opened on focus and need to stay till user focus on some other input.

Comment: Then the duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783030/jquery-datepicker-keep-open-after-selecting-a-date-and-close-with-the-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date)