# Auto Close is not working for date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have custom button inside date picker . Button Text: Done.

**Requirement:** when i click textbox, date picker should show and select some date . After clicking "DONE" button , selected date should display on text box and date picker should close.

I had set **autoclose** to **false** .

**Actual Output:**
I am getting date picker on click of textbox with "Done" button, but Whenever i selected any date, date picker is closing.

Am i doing anything wrong or have to append any more code .

```js
$(function () {
  $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    autoclose: false,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert('Date Selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    


<input class="datepicker1" type="text"  />
```

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a snippet please, there's a lot of library of datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [jQuery UI Datepicker API](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), doesn't seem like there is a `autoclose` option.

Utilizing the code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783030/jquery-datepicker-keep-open-after-selecting-a-date-and-close-with-the-button) adding to the `onSelect` event:

```js
$().ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert('Date Selected');
        
        // keep dialog open
        if (inst.inline)
         this._updateDatepicker(inst);
        else {
          this._hideDatepicker(null, this._get(inst, 'duration'));
          this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
          if (typeof(inst.input[0]) != 'object')
            inst.input[0].focus(); // restore focus
          this._lastInput = null;
        }
      }});
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class=datepicker1 type=text>
```

Comment: Hurray,, Both Yours & My answers are same. Thanks a lot for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

I added below code in OnSelect event

```
 if (inst.inline) this._updateDatepicker(inst);
                else {
                    this._hideDatepicker(null, this._get(inst, 'duration'));
                    this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
                    if (typeof (inst.input[0]) != 'object') inst.input[0].focus(); // restore focus
                    this._lastInput = null;
                }
```