# jQuery UI Datepicker, move from one Calendar to the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I'm looking for a way of moving from one Calendar to the next once the user has selected a date e.g:

- User picks `dateFrom`
- Automatically close `dateFrom` calendar and show `dateTo` version

I feel like I'm close to a solution but the `dateTo` calendar pops up and then disappears instantly, I'm hooking into the `onSelect` function of the calendar and when the `inst` is the `dateFrom` calendar, then i call `.focus()` on the `dateTo` text box e.g:

```
$('.datepicker > input').datepicker({
        // snip.....
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var type = $('#' + inst.id).data('calendar');
            if (type === 'date-from') {
                $('.js-hook--date-to').focus();
            }
        }
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <div class="datepicker">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" placeholder="CHECK IN" data-calendar="date-from" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <div class="datepicker">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" CssClass="js-hook--date-to" placeholder="CHECK OUT" data-calendar="date-to" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This causes the next Calendar to pop up but it then disappears, is there an easy way to achieve this?

Edit*

I've also tried using [.datepicker("show");](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) with no success.

2nd Edit*

[jsFiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/p89khLhu/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252512/jquery-datepicker-prevent-closing-picker-when-clicking-a-date)

Comment: @blgt How is that related at all? I want to show a different separate calendar object once a date has been selected in the first one. It has nothing to do with this issue unfortunately.

Comment: If you're using the widget out-of-the-box, it'll only draw one div on the page and reuse it for all input fields. You've already gotten the input swap with the `.focus()`, it looks like the problem is keeping it open. If this is not the case, could you make a MCVE?

Comment: Best way to help with this one is in a live demo. One suggestion is close current first...and use setTimeout() to trigger next. Will give a chance for plugin to clean up first one then build second one

Comment: @blgt That's fine, I don't intend to show both Calendars at the same time, the intention is to open the first, select a date, close it and then show the second one. I don't see how this is related to the proposed dupe? That guy is asking how to keep the calendar open after selecting a date..

Comment: *how to keep the calendar open after selecting a date* This is essentially the problem you've described above. You click a date, you swap the input, the datepicker closes because you've just clicked a date (it doesn't know/care you changed inputs) eg. in your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oanur2kn/

Comment: @charlietfl Added fiddle

Comment: @blgt I understand what you mean but I'm still not seeing how its related, I need the first calendar to *close* after select, my guess is the `focus()` is switching inputs too fast as @charlietfl states. The guy in the other thread is literally talking about keeping the calendar open `onSelect` so that he can pick a time (without requiring the 'Done' button), these aren't the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a short delay before triggering the focus.

```
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
   var type = $('#' + inst.id).data('calendar');
   if (type === 'date-from') {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $('.js-hook--date-to').focus();
     }, 50)

   }
 }
```

As mentioned in comments the plugin only uses one container for all instances.

I think what is happening is since the first instance hasn't quite closed and cleaned up when you trigger the focus, the new instance is getting hidden from event in first

I arbitrarily set the delay and didn't play with it much to see what is best.

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/p89khLhu/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It would be nice to do this without a timeout but this will suffice for now.

Comment: haven't looked in api...but there might be a `closed` event..not sure

Comment: Yeah, there's an `onClose`, i'm checking the `type` here instead and if the calendar has a date selected, moving to the next calendar object, this doesn't require a timeout, thanks for the help though, I'll add this as an answer in case it helps others.

Comment: @charlietfl No events. `datepicker` doesn't come out of the widget factory, and so has none of the standard mechanisms the other widgets use

Comment: @blgt seems there is .. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) and checking if a date was selected with `getDate`:

```
onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
      var picker = $('#' + inst.id);
      var type = picker.data('calendar');
      var date = picker.datepicker('getDate');
      if (type === 'date-from' && date !== null) {
            $('.js-hook--date-to').focus();
      }
}
```